Annual sSandardized Precipitation Index (SPI) - multiple colunms using precintcon R package
How to calculate and save annual SPI of multiple columns simultaneously using precintcon R package? I am using looping but I cannot save or extract the annual values ​​of the raingauges that are in the columns.
I want to save the SPI calculated for all raingauges (in columns), for each year analyzed.
library(precintcon)

#Creating a data.frame exemple using precintcon package
df=melt(daily,id = c("year","month"))
df$value2=1.2*df$value;df$value3=2+(df$value)*5;df$value4=3.9*df$value;df$value5=(df$value)*10;df$value6=df$value
colnames(df) <- c('year','month','day','RainGauge1','RainGauge2','RainGaue3','RainGauge4','RainGaue5','RainGauge6') 
head(df)

#Looping
ncol(df)
nproc = 6
cont = 1

for (i in 4:8) {
  
  print(i) 
  df2<-df[,-3]#
  nome.var=colnames(df2[i])
  variavela = nome.var[1]

  TIM = df2[,c(1,2,i)]
  TIM = na.omit(TIM)
  names(TIM) = c("Year","Month","Cd")
  head(TIM)
  df2=TIM
  #Here I calculate the annual SPI (standard precipitation index). 
  #I want to save the #results for the rain gauges that are in the columns, #in the same spreadsheet (see example below).
  names(df2)[1] <- "year"
  names(df2)[2] <- "month"
  names(df2)[3] <- "precipitation"
  
  df2=as.monthly(df2)
  head(df2)
  
  SPI=spi.per.year(df2, period = 12);SPI
  
  cont = cont + 1
  
}




I would like a result like the following, for all raingauge columns.
I tried the command: summarize(df, across(starts_with("RainGauge")
... but it didn't work.


It's sure not pretty, but we can apply the spi.per.year function to each column of df. Since precintcon requires a specific, unweildy data format, it gets messy.
library(plyr) # needed for join_all - not sure why that didn't make it into dplyr
SPI <- apply(
  select(df, starts_with("RainGauge")), # only apply to RainGauge columns
  2, # 2 = apply over columns
  function(x) {
    spi.per.year(
      data.frame(year=df$year, month=df$month, day=df$day, precipiation=x) %>% # add the year/month/day back in
        dcast(year + month ~ day, value.var = "precipiation") %>% # "un-melt" the dataframe back into something precintcon can stomach
        as.daily, # convert into a precintcon.daily object
      period=12
    )
  }
) %>% join_all(by = "year") # apply gives a list of dataframes, so this joins them into one with only one column for year
colnames(SPI)[colnames(SPI) == "spi.FUN"] <- colnames(select(df, starts_with("RainGauge"))) # then give our new dataframe the rain gauge column names from the original df

> head(SPI)
  year RainGauge1 RainGauge2 RainGauge3 RainGauge4 RainGauge5 RainGauge6
1 1976  1.1267902  1.1267902  1.1300578  1.1267902  1.1267902  1.1267902
2 1977  0.4973457  0.4973457  0.4945768  0.4973457  0.4973457  0.4973457
3 1978 -0.7637241 -0.7637241 -0.7657354 -0.7637241 -0.7637241 -0.7637241
4 1979 -1.0955404 -1.0955404 -1.0919097 -1.0955404 -1.0955404 -1.0955404
5 1980  0.6698690  0.6698690  0.6676841  0.6698690  0.6698690  0.6698690
6 1981 -0.4516461 -0.4516461 -0.4554376 -0.4516461 -0.4516461 -0.4516461


You could use tidyverse here, with a bit of tidying since your rows and columns need to be switched before using the spi.per.year function.
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(precintcon)

pivot_longer(df, -c(1:3)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from=day) |>
  nest(data=-name) |>
  mutate(SPI=lapply(data, \(x) data.frame(spi.per.year(as.daily(x), period=12)))) |>
  unnest(SPI) |>
  select(-data) |>
  pivot_wider(values_from=spi.FUN)

Which gives:
# A tibble: 35 × 7
    year RainGauge1 RainGauge2 RainGaue3 RainGauge4 RainGaue5 RainGauge6
   <int>      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
 1  1976      1.13       1.13      1.13       1.13      1.13       1.13 
 2  1977      0.497      0.497     0.495      0.497     0.497      0.497
 3  1978     -0.764     -0.764    -0.766     -0.764    -0.764     -0.764
 4  1979     -1.10      -1.10     -1.09      -1.10     -1.10      -1.10 
 5  1980      0.670      0.670     0.668      0.670     0.670      0.670
 6  1981     -0.452     -0.452    -0.455     -0.452    -0.452     -0.452
 7  1982      0.565      0.565     0.561      0.565     0.565      0.565
 8  1983      2.29       2.29      2.31       2.29      2.29       2.29 
 9  1984     -0.333     -0.333    -0.330     -0.333    -0.333     -0.333
10  1985     -0.421     -0.421    -0.425     -0.421    -0.421     -0.421
# ℹ 25 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

